# Permission denied error while using wget

Tags: permissions, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda on WSL in the `/mnt/c/Windows/System32` directory and use the following command:

```
sudo wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

However, I got an error in the result (here is the output in the terminal):

```
--2020-07-06 14:36:43--  https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.131.3, 104.16.130.3, 2606:4700::6810:8203, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.131.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 685906562 (654M) [application/x-sh]
Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh’ (Success).
```

It seems that some special access right to download with `wget` is required to be specified (please, correct me if my understanding of the problem is wrong here).

How to solve the issue?

Comment: why do you use `sudo` ? Which working directory are you at? ( Output of `pwd` from same place would be good)

Comment: I saw on the forums that that in some cases `sudo` at the beginning helped to solve the issue. The working directory is `/mnt/c/Windows/System32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System32` is a protected Windows directory and is probably the reason for your error.

Please download and install Anaconda (without `sudo`) in another directory for which you have proper access, such as the Windows `Documents` or your Ubuntu `Home` directory.